# Unable to encrypt Azure storage account using ansible

Tags: azure, ansible

I am unable to set encryption for the storage account once the storage account created successfully. I am creating the below playbooks for the storage account and encryption.

```yaml
- name: storage_account_creation | deploy storage account
  azure_rm_storageaccount:
    state: present
    cloud_environment: "AzureCloud"
    subscription_id: "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXX"
    resource_group_name: "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX"
    client_id: "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX"
    secret: "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX"
    tenant: "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXX"
    location: "{{ azloc['stdout_lines'][0] }}"
    kind: BlobStorage
    access_tier: "Hot"
    name: "storageaccount_001"
    account_type: "Standard_LRS"
    network_acls:
      bypass: AzureServices
      default_action: deny
```

---

### encrypt.yml

```yaml
 - name: encrypt | Get keyvault name from id 
   set_fact:
     keyvaultname: "XXXXXXXXXX"

 - name: encrypt | Get object id of storage account
   shell: az storage account show --subscription "{{ subscription_id }}" -n "{{ Storageaccount_name }}" --query "identity.principalId" --output tsv
   register: azsaobjectid

 - debug:
    var: azsaobjectid
    
 - name: encrypt | Create key vault access policy for new storage account
   shell: az keyvault set-policy --subscription "{{ subscription_id }}" -n {{ keyvaultname }}" --key-permissions get wrapKey unwrapKey --object-id "{{ azsaobjectid.stdout_lines[0] }}"
```

When I execute the scripts I get the below error

---

```sh
    fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! =>
      msg: |-
        The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: list object has no element 0
    
        The error appears to be in 'encrypt.yml': line 10, column 4, but may
        be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
    
    The offending line appears to be:    
         - name:  encrypt | Create key vault access policy for new storage account
           ^ here
```

Comment: Vicky, I see your new here, so please don't take this the wrong way. Your question was initially very difficult to read. Try to make sure you've formatted your question clearly, so that answerers can easily parse your question. Use code blocks where appropriate, and it really makes things easier!

Answer (score 0):

The error details suggest that you are using a variable that hasn't been defined. I suspect this is from your `register` block in `get object id of storage account`.

**However...**

Consider re-writing these tasks to use [official azure modules](https://galaxy.ansible.com/azure/azcollection?extIdCarryOver=true&sc_cid=701f2000001OH7YAAW).

Shelling out should be a last resort, and from the look of it, you can accomplish your goal by using the [azure_rm_storageaccount_info_module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/azure/azcollection/azure_rm_storageaccount_info_module.html) module to gather facts, and [azure_rm_keyvault](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/azure/azcollection/azure_rm_keyvault_module.html#parameter-access_policies) module to set your policy.

Using official modules ensures your playbook is idempotent, easier to read, and your error details will likely become clearer as well.